# How to know the list of possible commands when in a session?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, keymap, help

For instance: When I am in `C-c C-e` (export), by pressing # you get extra options. How to know this?

Another example: When in a helm session, by pressing `C-c C-f`, you activate `helm-follow-mode`. But this is not obvious.

Is there a "help" shortcut to show potential keys in such buffers?
Thanks!

Comment: How about: `C-h` ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. I get the impression you are really trying to ask what keys are available onthe prefix key `C-c` in some particular context. (And if so, one answer to that is to use `C-h`: `C-c C-h`.)

Comment: Assuming you are talking about `C-c C-e` in Org mode, there is no way to use a general mechanism to see what keys are bound there, simply because that is not a mode with its own keymap, it's a menu constructed by `org-export-dispatch` internally. The only things that are recognized are the things that the menu shows you: the various key combos to export using a particular backend, whether to use a buffer or a file (and whether to show the result) and various other things among which `#` inserts  a template of options for the category (or backend) of your choice. I know nothing about helm.

Comment: BTW, for the Org mode export case, if you don't see the menu, then check the value of `org-export-use-expert-ui`. If it is non-nil, you might want to set it to nil, so you can see the menu.

Comment: Thanks. I have clarified my question. I see that there is not a way to see the available keys in a session. I just learned about the #, which it wasn't obvious. But I had to look it up.

Comment: As for org-export-use-expert-ui, I don't have that variable.

Comment: Apologies: the variable is called `org-export-dispatch-use-expert-ui`. The `#` key is at the bottom of the menu, labeled `Insert template`; it is next to the `&` key, labeled `Export stack`, and `q` which exits `org-export-dispatch` without doing anything.

Comment: Thanks. When I (setq org-export-dispatch-use-expert-ui t) and then C-c C-e, I get just one line in the mini-buffer "Export command (C-bvsfa) [cfhlostP&?q]. What does this mean? I rather have the bigger menu!

Comment: I said if it is non-nil, set it to nil, not the other way round.

Comment: Ok, I see it now :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I may consider you thought about "..a way to see the available keys in a session." then you are probably looking for documentation depending on the mode you are in right now.

1. If it is just about keybindings then I highly recommend the `which-key` package. Basically this allows you to stop in the middle of any prefix-key and displays follow up solutions in a popup-buffer
2. If it is about the major mode you are interested in, then you should have a look at `C-h i`. This will let you navigate through most of your installed packages built in documentation. Not every mode/package is fully documented but e.g. the Org-Mode part is great and I actually learned a lot about stuff I wasn't even aware of.
3. If it is about an overview of the current major and all minor modes that are active then you are probably searching for `C-h m` that will give you an overview of e.g. active modes, prefix keys and so on.

I hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for this, not exactly what I asked, but useful in other contexts. One thing: C-h i is boung in my Emacs to "C-h i runs the command info", so it is a list of major topics in Emacs, I understood you said it would give me a list of the major modes I was in.

Comment: You are right. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

I second the recommendation to use `which-key`. It's been a valuable part of my configuration for some time.